# Отображение экземпляра Hint'a на карте

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Следуя инструкции к классу Hint https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Hint.html

Создаю новый экземпляр Hint'а, но при попытке открыть через метод open я получаю ошибку *Overlay wasn't found*

```
initOverlay() {

  const hint = new this.yandex.Hint(this.map, {
    projection: this.yandex.projection.wgs84Mercator,
    layout: this.yandex.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      `<div class="yandex-map__myhint">{{ label }}</div>`,
    ),
  });
  hint
    .open(this.myhint.coordinates, this.myhint)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Error: Overlay wasn't found
at Function.c.OverlayNotFound (full-6341f0c1e121ed8c4cbf1c6d8dc350380d538a9a.js:1004:773)
at Object.<anonymous> (full-6341f0c1e121ed8c4cbf1c6d8dc350380d538a9a.js:1004:870)
at t.<anonymous> (2.1?onload=__yandexCallback&apiKey=&lang=ru_RU:1:20949)
at Array.<anonymous> (2.1?onload=__yandexCallback&apiKey=&lang=ru_RU:1:5873)
at r (2.1?onload=__yandexCallback&apiKey=&lang=ru_RU:1:674)
at run (setImmediate.js:40:13)
at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:69:21)
at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:109:17)
```

Что я делаю не так? Что за Overlay от меня хочет Hint и где его взять?

Comment: А можете объяснить, зачем вы пытаетесь использовать оверлей? В простейшем случае независимый хинт ставится на карту одной строкой: myMap.hint.open(myMap.getCenter(), "Одинокий хинт", {openTimeout: 1500}); В песочнице есть и более сложная схема, но ей также не нужно прикручивать оверлей - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_hint_layout

Comment: Задача в общем такая, мне нужно для маркеров сделать наподобие перемещаемых балунов с помощью курсора. Это необходимо, когда на карте маркеры находятся слишком близко друг другу, чтобы их наложенные друг на друга балуны можно было переместить на карте, соответственно со стрелочками к своим маркерам. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Можете подсказать, что лучше использовать?

Comment: Создавать массу объектов типа hint или balloon, когда они изначально спроектированы как одиночная сущность - далеко не лучший подход. Вам стоит смотреть в сторону работы с кастомными метками их формой/шаблоном - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape Или же включить кластеризацию

Comment: Спасибо большое за поддержку!)